# Find different values in a multiple dictionary with same set of keys

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of multiple dictionaries that I need to compare. The number of dictionaries within the list will change depending on the result from a query.

Example list of dictionary with the same keys but different values:

```
test = [{'a':'1','b':'1','c':'4'},{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'5'},{'a':'1','b':'3','c':'6'}]
```

**desired output:**

```
[{'b':'1','c':'4'},{'b':'2','c':'5'},{'b':'3','c':'6'}]
```

I want to be able to output what keys(with values) is different on the list(if there's any) and if there's none output an empty list.

I tried this code but its giving me the ones with the same values.

```
mysets = (set(x.items()) for x in test)
print reduce(set.intersection, mysets)
```

**output:**

```
{'a':'1'}
```

I've also tried this one, but its only giving me the different pairs on the first dictionary.

```
def IntersectDicts( d1, d2 ) :
    return dict(filter(lambda (k,v) : k in d2 and d2[k] != v, d1.items()))

result = reduce(IntersectDicts, test)
print result
```

**output:**

```
{'b': '1', 'c': '4'}
```

Comment: Which type you want out put???? like {'a': '1', 'c': '6', 'b': '3'}

Comment: sorry, i edited the question @user00000341, its the first ouput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote two solutions to solve your problem.

1. Loop solution:

```
test = [{'a':'1','b':'1','c':'4'},{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'5'},{'a':'1','b':'3','c':'6'}]
keys = set()

def loop_solution():
    for key,val in test[0].items():
        for item in test[1:]:
            if item[key] != val:
                keys.add(key)
```

2. Functional solution

```
def is_duplicate_value(p_key,p_value):
    for item_dict in test:
        if item_dict[p_key] != p_value:
            return True
    return False

def func_solution():
    for key,val in test[0].items():
        if is_duplicate_value(key,val):
            keys.add(key)
```

If you don't want to call another function then choose the first solution. But I would recommend the second solution since it is more readable.

Comment: Thanks @RockOnGom, i used the first solution, though its only returning the keys.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code

```
import copy

test = [{'a':'1','b':'1','c':'4'},{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'5'},{'a':'1','b':'3','c':'6'}]

ftest = copy.deepcopy(test)
keyy = ''
for d in range(len(test)):
    ftest[d] = {}
    for k, y in test[d].items():
        for f in range(len(ftest)):
            if k in ftest[f] and y == ftest[f].get(k):
                keyy = k
                ftest[f].pop(k)
                test[f] = ftest[f]
    if keyy:
        test[d].pop(keyy)
        keyy = ''
    ftest = copy.copy(test)
print 'TESTINGGGGG  ---------------------', test
```